# What does x:Double mean for a Xamarin Button?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My code has:

```
<Button x:Name="correctButton" HeightRequest="60" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
   <Button.FontSize>
      <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="25" Android="20" />
   </Button.FontSize>
</Button>
```

Can someone explain what x:Double means

Comment: it is parameter of FontSize on the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have broken it down for you with comments in the XAML.

```
<!-- Here is the button declared, note how you also see the x:Name here -->
<Button x:Name="correctButton" HeightRequest="60" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
   <!-- Besides giving properties to a control, in this case a button, as attributes, you can also set them by adding them as child nodes. That is what happens with the FontSize here -->
   <Button.FontSize>
      <!-- We are not just setting the FontSize here, we are also letting the value be dependent on which platform we are running on. For iOS the value will be 25, for Android 20. -->
      <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="25" Android="20" />
   </Button.FontSize>
</Button>
```

Now, the `x:Double` is needed to tell the `OnPlatform` tag which type we should provide to it, this can also be x:Int32 or any other type if needed. Because we will always provide string values in the OnPlatform tag, it needs to know to what type it has to cast the value.

Remember that I pointed out to you also the `x:Name` property. the `x` is a shorthand for the namespace where to find the type. If you look at your page declaration, it will probably have an attribute like: `xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"`, see how the `x` is declared here? That is why the `x` is needed in front, to tell the XAML that the `Double` type can be found in the `http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml` namespace, abbreviated to `x` by default.

Note that the `OnPlatform` tag in this way is deprecated as of Xamarin.Forms 2.3.4. You should now use it as such:

```
<Button x:Name="correctButton" HeightRequest="60" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
   <Button.FontSize>
       <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" x:Key="WindowBackgroundTable">
           <On Platform="Android" Value="20" />
           <On Platform="iOS" Value="25" />
       </OnPlatform>  
   </Button.FontSize>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Sorry for the poor english.

When used in XAML this tag needs the type of the value you're sending to the property, once this is a generic method. I belive that XF uses reflection and castings to set the attribute to the specific platform.

See more in [this article](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/essential_xaml_syntax/).

I hope it helps you.